# What is the right way to install cython in windows 10 and anaconda?

Tags: cython

I'm trying to run Cython codes inside jupyter notebook in windows 10 , but I receive this error:

> "Unable to find vcvarsall. bat"

My anaconda version is 3.7.3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python distutils refuses to recognise installed C++ compilers, \`Unable to find vcvarsall.bat\` under Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020247/python-distutils-refuses-to-recognise-installed-c-compilers-unable-to-find-v)

Comment: Might also be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663642/how-can-i-get-64-bit-anaconda-python-to-find-the-ms-c-compiler-for-cython-on-win. There's probably other questions. If these _don't_ help you then some evidence of what you've tried from these questions would probably be useful

Comment: I have the latest visual studio on my laptop. Should I install another version of Anaconda?

Comment: I don't think you necessarily want the latest version of Visual C - I think you want the [one that Python was compiled](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) - when. You can just download the compiler as a standalone though - you don't need the whole of Visual Studio. However, I don't have Python installed and set-up on Windows, so I'm not sure I can give you too much advice